npm install not working on windows server 2016
I want to run my node.js application on a windows server.
(I'm new to react and node)
I've created a folder, copied my source to this folder.
completed the IIS part but could not install packages.

npm install command results in error.
for example :
C:\inetpub\reactServer>npm install bcrypt
npm WARN package.json kmysistem_server@1.0.0 No README.md file found!
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bcrypt
npm ERR! Error: 5672:error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:602:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream._puller (tls.js:501:24)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream._pull (tls.js:432:19)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:727:20)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.write (tls.js:130:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at TCP.onread (net.js:367:14)
npm ERR!  [Error: 5672:error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:602:
npm ERR! ]
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! cwd C:\inetpub\reactServer
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37
npm ERR! message 5672:error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:602:
npm ERR! message
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\inetpub\reactServer\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code undefined
npm ERR! not ok code 1

what should I do?
